# How to keep space char in JSON when convert datatable by C# to json

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql, json

I fill a **datatable** by `sqldatareader` in C#,
and convert the **datatable** into **json** format,
and then use jquery to catch **json** to show.

The following is code in C#

```
string JSONString = string.Empty;
JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datatable));
HiddenField.Value = JSONString;
```

My problem is my data in datatable is something like `"Kelly LI"`,
but I get json in jquery is `"KellyLI"`.
The space char is missing, but i want to keep.

Please tell me how to do, thanks a lot!

Comment: This code does not remove space char. The problem is related to something else. What is the type of your datatable object ?

Comment: What is the type of the `datatable`? When you say it is `"Kelly LI"`, what do you mean by it?

Comment: @PMerlet the type of datatable is `DataTable` in C#, and data in there is string type.

Comment: @Prateek i mean like my **column name is "name"** and **data in a row is "Kelly LI"**, and I hope to get `{"name","Kelly LI"}` in json, but i get  `{"name","KellyLI"}`

Comment: @PMerlet I found I process some special char in jQuery, and i can solve the problem, thanks!